# What is the proper virtual directory access permission level required for a SOAP web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, file-permissions

When setting up a new virtual directory for hosting a SOAP web service in IIS 6.0 on a Server 2003 box I am required to set the access permissions for the virtual directory.  The various permissions are to allow/disallow the following:

- **Read**
- **Run scripts (such as ASP)**
- **Execute (such as ISAPI or CGI)**
- **Write**
- **Browse**

The SOAP web service is being published through the SOAP3.0 ISAPI server with the extensions set to "Allowed" in the Web Service Extensions pane of the IIS Manager.

Since I don't want to expose the contents of this directory to the web I know **Browse** is not desirable.  But, I *don't* know if I need to have the **Run scripts**, **Execute**, and **Write** permissions enabled to properly publish this web service.  The web service is being used to send and receive XML data sets between the server and remote clients. **What is the correct level of access permission for my SOAP web service's virtual directory?**

Comment: you'll need read, run scripts at a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon further examination, I've come to the conclusion that one assumption I had about *needing* Read permissions was incorrect.
SOAP web services only need the "Run scripts" permission enabled because the `.wsdl` apparently comes from the web service in the form of a script execution response. So the minimum required for a SOAP3.0 web service's directory is **Run scripts**.